# checking a Python dictionary for specific keys

Tags: python

There are several different ways to check if a Python dictionary contains a specific key, i.e.

```
d = {}

if key in d:

if d.contains(key):

if d.has_key(key):
```

it's silly for a language to allow you to do the same thing several different ways, UNLESS, each of the methods was doing something entirely different.  Could someone please contrast the  three techniques above, how are they different?

Comment: never seen d.contains(), is that new?

Comment: @steabert: probably should be `__contains__`

Comment: ah, thanks, didn't think about that, I tend to stay clear from those :)

Comment: "It's silly for a language to allow you to do the same thing several different ways" -- if that's the case, Python is one of the less silly of a very large number of extremely silly languages.

Comment: nice question.  i will now go and change all my `.has_key` to `in`  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d.__contains__(key)` is what is used it `key in d` (since `in` operator calls `__contains__` method of the dictionary)

`has_key` is deprecated and does the same as `__contains__`

Answer (score 12):

They're all the same and they're all around for historical reasons, but you [should use](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key) `key in d`.

Comment: I don't think that `__contains__` is "around for historical reasons"?  It's not like it's going to be deprecated any time soon…

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to elaborate further for the benefit of the querent?

Answer (score 7):

Method #1 is the accepted way to do it.  Method #2 doesn't actually exist, at least in any versions of Python that I'm aware of; I'd be interested to see where you found that.  Method #3 used to be the accepted way, but is now [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key).

So there really is just one way.

Comment: maybe he was thinking of `__contains__`

Comment: Just to piggback on this answer... if he *was* thinking of `__contains__` - the answer is that it is a special method used to implement `b in a`... the vm translates any `b in a` references into a call to `a.__contains__(b)` behinds the scenes, much like `a[b]` is translated to `a.__getitem__(b)`. The special `__xxx__` methods are how python provides a clean method-based implementation of all the syntactic sugar the language publically offers.

Answer (score 4):

- `key in d` is the accepted way to do it.
- `__contains__` is the ‘“magic” attribute’ ([ref](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) that implements the above syntax.  Most, if not all, special syntax is implemented via such methods.  E.g., the `with` statement is implemented via `__enter__` and `__exit__`.  Such methods exist for allowing special functionality to be provided for user-defined classes.
- the `has_key` method no longer exists in Python 3 and is deprecated in Python 2.

Comment: @NullUserException: Thanks, I looked up the proper name for it.